# Converting cURL to browser request?

Tags: rest, api, curl, post

I have a POST query in Postman for sending SMS that works just fine.

[image]

But I want to invoke this request through my browser. I get the below error *[Full disclosure: I am not sure what such a request is called. I am pretty new to this]*

[image]

Comment: These are using different HTTP request methods. [This article may help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods). Specifically, Postman is using the POST method, but your browser is using the GET method.

Comment: that helped very little. I am not sure what exactly is to be done to be honest.